# Where is TimeZoneType?

Tags: python-3.4, python-c-api, python-datetime

In the C API structure in datetime.h, I see the following type objects:

```
PyTypeObject *DateType;
PyTypeObject *DateTimeType;
PyTypeObject *TimeType;
PyTypeObject *DeltaType;
PyTypeObject *TZInfoType;
```

But there is no:

```
TimeZoneType
```

I need to instantiate a datetime.timezone object to make a datetime.datetime object aware.

I would have called:

```
PyObject *tzobj = PyObject_CallObject(PyDateTimeAPI->TimeZoneType, argList);
```

and then the replace(tzinfo=...) method on datetime object

But I can't do that.

What is the alternative to construct a aware datetime object from C/C++ ?

Answer (score 1):

The type you're looking for is defined in *Lib/datetime.py*

```
class timezone(tzinfo):
    [...]
```

so you might need to do a `from datetime import timezone` to get this type.

```
static PyObject*
load_timezone_type(void) {
    PyObject *dt = PyImport_ImportModule("datetime");
    if (!dt) return NULL;
    PyObject *tz = PyObject_GetAttrString(dt, "timezone");
    Py_DECREF(dt);
    return tz;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The timezone class has not been exposed in datetime C API yet.  See [issue 10381](http://bugs.python.org/issue10381).